# How can I loop 3 pandas DataFrames which classify as 'positive', 'negative', and 'neutral' and list them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, class

[Input example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfoSY.png)

I have 1D probability data (as DataFrame) and based on their value, I want to classify them as 'positive', 'negative', and 'neutral'.

Example outcome:

`Classes = ['positive', 'neutral','negative',....]`

Here is my script:

```
for i in mle_positive, mle_negative, mle_neutral:

        cond = [((mle_positive.iloc[i] > mle_negative.iloc[i]).all(axis=0) and (mle_positive.iloc[i] > mle_neutral.iloc[i]).all(axis=0)),
        ((mle_negative.iloc[i] > mle_positive.iloc[i]).all(axis=0) and (mle_negative.iloc[i] > mle_neutral.iloc[i]).all(axis=0)),
        ((mle_neutral.iloc[i] > mle_negative.iloc[i]).all(axis=0) and (mle_neutral.iloc[i] > mle_positive.iloc[i]).all(axis=0)),
        ((mle_neutral.iloc[i] == mle_negative.iloc[i]).all(axis=0) and (mle_neutral.iloc[i] == mle_positive.iloc[i]).all(axis=0)),
        ((mle_negative.iloc[i] == mle_positive.iloc[i]).all(axis=0) and (mle_negative.iloc[i] == mle_neutral.iloc[i]).all(axis=0)),
        ((mle_neutral.iloc[i] == mle_negative.iloc[i]).all(axis=0) and (mle_neutral.iloc[i] == mle_positive.iloc[i]).all(axis=0))]

        idx = ['positive', 'negative', 'neutral', 'neutral', 'neutral', 'neutral']

        classes = np.select(cond, idx, default = '')
```

And the error is:

**ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)**

Glad, if you guys can help.

Comment: So to see if I'm following the code correctly... if mle_positive is greater than both mle_negative and mle_neutral, you want that labeled as "positive" in a new column?

Comment: Add a sample of your input data, together with the corresponding (expected) output.

Comment: @Tom , you're correct.

Comment: And these are three different dataframes?

Comment: yeah, and I added the example input @Tom

Comment: @DanielMesejo I did

Comment: I meant in a way it can be copied into a text editor

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary that they be in three different dfs? Because this would be extremely easy if they were merged.

Comment: @DanielMesejo sorry, the data is too big.

Comment: @Tom No, I can merge them. Only important thing is the order of classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your data, I don't know the precise way you should merge the dataframes, but here's my idea. Let's assume you somehow get the dataframe such that there are three relevant columns: 'mle_positive', 'mle_neutral', 'mle_negative'

Then it seems you are looking for the maximum of these three columns. You do that with `idxmax`.

```
check_cols = ['mle_positive', 'mle_neutral', 'mle_negative']
df['Class_cat'] = df[check_cols].idxmax(axis=1)
```

Then 'Class_cat' (I don't like using 'Class' as a header since it is a special word) should look something like:

```
0    mle_positive
1    mle_neutral
2    mle_positive
3    mle_negative
```

Then if you really want to get rid of the "mle_" you can do it with `replace`

```
df.replace({'mle_':''}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Should also be way faster :)